# How to use Non-Renewable Subscriptions in multiple devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I'm implementing an application with Non-Renewal Subscriptions. For that i have referred many sites and most of the answers that i found as like,

- We need to manage the expire date by ourself in our server side/local, once you verify a receipt with Apple.
- We can implement authentication module as optional to share use the Non-Renewal Subscriptions across multiple devices.

Actually my application doesn't have authentication modules like registration/login to track user on multiple devices. So How can i able to use the Non-Renewable in multiple devices without allowing user to register/login. Do we have any common field to trace the user on multiple devices without authenticating them.

Thanks in advance, Can anyone please give any suggestions to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need some server side support. If you are fine with receiving unauthenticated traffic, you can use the original transaction id. For each subscription purchase you make for a given Apple Id, that purchase will have a unique original transaction id (in the receipt).

If the user initially purchases the subscription on device A, let's say they get back a transaction id of 1234 (note this is not the format, I am just using this as an example). Now the user goes to device B and makes the same purchase. Note this is a subscription, so Apple will already know the purchase was made for that Apple Id. It will indicate the subscription was already purchased, but will let the person still "purchase" (they won't be charged). Upon this, they will get a receipt. This receipt will have the same transaction id.

So here is where your server would need to tie the two together. You would most likely use a UUID, such as `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]`. Now your server will know that transaction id 1234 is used by device A and device B.

You can choose how to send this information. You can either send it by way of the receipt (in which case your server will need to unpack it to get the transaction id) or the app can do it for you.

You should do what you can to increase security measures. For example, the method above could be easily spoofed.

Comment: Thanks @Mobile Ben, But UUID will be changed whenever we delete and install the app. Anyway thanks for the information about getting the same transaction id when purchasing the same product again.